# BitField serialization using Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-bitfield

I have a model that contains a [`BitField`](https://github.com/disqus/django-bitfield). When trying to serialize an object using Django Rest Framework, the following error is returned:

```
{"flags": ["Enter a whole number."]}
```

(`flags` is a `BitField`)

How can I serialize a `BitField` using Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 4):

looks like the form of Tzach's answer in rest-framework 3.1 is now

```
class BitFieldSerializer(serializers.Field):

     def to_internal_value(self, obj):
         return int(obj)
```

e.g. per http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields

"Note that the WritableField class that was present in version 2.x **no longer exists**. You should subclass Field and override to_internal_value() if the field supports data input."

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. I needed to create a custom serializer for the `BitField`:

```
class BitFieldSerializer(serializers.WritableField):        
    def to_native(self, obj):
        return int(obj)
```

And use it in the model serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    flags = BitFieldSerializer()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option if you want to read and write the flags in a list.

```
class BitFieldSerializer(serializers.Field):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        model_field = getattr(self.root.Meta.model, self.source)
        result = BitHandler(0, model_field.keys())
        for k in data:
            try:
                setattr(result, str(k), True)
            except AttributeError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Unknown choice: %r" % (k,))
        return result

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return [i[0] for i in value.items() if i[1] is True]
```

Example return: `['flag1', 'flag4']`

This assumes you are using a ModelSerializer. The way I get the model field's keys (it's flags) seems a little sketchy if anyone knows a better way please comment.

Comment: thanks a lot! This makes it more feasible because with django-bitfield, we don't get the right bit-wise values as a flag. It makes it very hard for clients to make changes to the field